# I need a probability statement

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I need some help with this question please.
Make a probability statement about a group of workers who produced product data with a mean of 20 and a standard deviation of 1.03.

Comment: I just need to make a probability statement about  a group of workers who produced a product and the data mean was 20 and with a standard deviation of 1.03.   At first glance I thought it was going to be simple but now i am not so sure on the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the instructor intended you to use Chebyshev's Inequality is ...